# How back to Compose from Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I have a case
MainScreenCompose in MainActivity go to AnotherActivity and back to MainScreenCompose
simple: ComposeOne ➡️ AnotherActivity ➡️ ComposeOne

> in ComposeOne

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val intent = Intent(context, AnotherActivity::class.java)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

> in AnotherActivity

```
HOW BACK TO ComposeOne Navigation
```

thank for attention

Try Navigation mixed compose and activity, I hope can navigation.

Comment: You can back up in the task to the previous activity by calling `finish()`. It's not clear to me whether you're using the Navigation Component library or not. If you are, you may need to do this through the Navigation Component instead of calling `finish()`.